# Making a D3.js stacked bar chart responsive

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a D3.js (v5) stacked bar chart to resize responsively. I had something similar working with a standard bar chart but something about the new groups containing the stacked bars has me stumped... Currently the bars resize but the previous ones remain.

[Here's a CodePen of my reasonably minimal example code.](https://codepen.io/philgyford/pen/yLajyWr)

From that, here's the `renderBars()` function that's called on page load and when the page resizes:

```js
function renderBars() {

  // Calculating the x, y, width and height of a bar:
  var barX = function(d, i) { return xScale(d.data.label); };
  var barY = function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); };
  var barW = xScale.bandwidth();
  var barH = function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]); };

  // Surrounds all of the barGroups:
  var barGroupsContainer = inner.append("g");

  // One barGroup per kind/colour of bar:
  var barGroups = barGroupsContainer
    .selectAll(".bargroup")
    .data(seriesData)
    .enter().append("g")
      .classed("bargroup", true)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.key); });

  // Each bar is within its barGroup:
  var bars = barGroups
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; });

  // ENTER
  bars
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", barX)
      .attr("y", barY)
      .attr("width", barW)
      .attr("height", barH);

  // UPDATE
  bars
    .transition()
    .attr("x", barX)
    .attr("y", barY)
    .attr("width", barW)
    .attr("height", barH);

  // EXIT
  bars.exit().remove();
}
```

I've tried various combinations of updating and removing `barGroupsContainer` and `barGroups` as well as `bars`, but with no improvement.

(Any other critiques always welcome!)

**UPDATE:** I'm not looking to make this responsive using `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` and a `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` - that would resize everything in the chart, including any texts, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues:

First, the scope of the `barGroupsContainer` variable (having it in the `renderBars` function) means that right off the bat you are creating a parent `g` that everything else goes into on each re-size.  The means every element was always "entering".

Second, even fixing that you aren't properly handling the `enter`/`update` pattern on the wrapper `g` around each set of `rect`s.  You only handled `enter`...

Here's a quick rewrite:

```js
// Prepare data

var data = [
  {"label": "2000", "dogs": 23, "cats": 30, "fish": 5},
  {"label": "2001", "dogs": 27, "cats": 19, "fish": 8},
  {"label": "2002", "dogs": 35, "cats": 25, "fish": 10},
];
var groupKeys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
var seriesData = d3.stack().keys(groupKeys)(data)


// Initial dimensions and scales

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0};
var chartW;
var chartH;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) { return d.label; })
  );
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    0,
    d3.max(seriesData, function(d) { return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d[1]})})
  ]);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(groupKeys)
  .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])

// Prepare containing elements.

var container = d3.select(".container");
var svg = container.append("svg");
var inner = svg.append("g");
// Surrounds all of the barGroups:
var barGroupsContainer = inner.append("g");

// Do initial render, and re-render on resize:

render();
window.addEventListener("resize", render);

function render() {
  sizeChart();
  renderBars();
}

function sizeChart() {
  var width = parseInt(container.style("width"), 10);
  var height = parseInt(container.style("height"), 10);

  chartW = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  chartH = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  xScale.range([0, chartW]).padding(0.1);
  yScale.rangeRound([chartH, 0]);

  svg
    .transition()
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

  inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
}

function renderBars() {

  // Calculating the x, y, width and height of a bar:
  var barX = function(d, i) { return xScale(d.data.label); };
  var barY = function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); };
  var barW = xScale.bandwidth();
  var barH = function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]); };

  // One barGroup per kind/colour of bar:
  
  // ENTER
  var barGroups = barGroupsContainer
    .selectAll(".bargroup")
    .data(seriesData);
  
  // ENTER + UPDATE
  barGroups = barGroups
    .enter().append("g")
    .merge(barGroups)
    .classed("bargroup", true)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.key); });
  
  // Each bar is within its barGroup:
  var bars = barGroups
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { 
      return d; 
    });

  // ENTER
  bars = bars
    .enter().append("rect")
    .merge(bars);
      //.attr("x", barX)
      //.attr("y", barY)
      //.attr("width", barW)
      //.attr("height", barH);

  // UPDATE
  bars
    .transition()
    .attr("x", barX)
    .attr("y", barY)
    .attr("width", barW)
    .attr("height", barH);

  // EXIT
  bars.exit().remove();
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I'd have stumbled across that. One question: when I've used patterns like this previously, having to set the bars' x, y, width and height on both enter and update seems repetitive - is that normal and unavoidable? Or is there a less repetitive way to do the same thing?

Comment: @PhilGyford, you can remove the double assignment.  The only artifact of doing that is you'll see the bars transition in on creation.  See edited snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Add viewBox as an attribute to the SVG element and then set the width and height within the viewbox.

So it will look something like this using template literals:

```
svg.attr('viewBox',`0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
```

If you wanted your bars to stack into a column from a row, I'd render 3 SVGs and then use CSS flexbox to handle switching from row to column as the screen size changes.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix the issue - the previous bars remain. I should also have said, that I'm not looking to make this responsive by using `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` on the svg, which is one solution, because that also resizes any text elements.